# Determine a cycle in a matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix, cycle

I have a matrix and each cell has a boolean property. I need to determine a cycle, starting from a cell that has the boolean property false, and this cycle must contain only cells that have that boolean property set to true (except the starting cell, obviously). Another condition is that any two consecutive cells in the cycle must be on the same row (or on the same column), and that three consecutive cells in the cycle must not be on the same row (or on the same column).
You can actually jump from one cell to another, they don't have to be neighbours, they just have to be on the same row or column.
Thank you.

Comment: Please define what a cycle is in this setting.

Comment: A cycle would be an array of cells, the first cell in the array would be starting cell, and all the others would have to respect the mentioned conditions. The sequence of cells should end with the starting cell.

Comment: If "any two consecutive cells in the cycle must be on the same row" then any three consecutive cells must also be in the same row, violating your condition "three consecutive cells in the cycle must not be on the same row". Lets say A, B and C are three consecutive cells in that order. Meaning A and B are two consecutive cells and B and C are two consecutive cells. By the first condition A and B are in the same row and B and C are in the same row. This implies (obviously) that A, B and C are all in the same row. The setup as you have put right now, seems impossible. You need to revise it.

Comment: Same row or column, my mistake.

Comment: Essentially you have to walk on the cells of a grid with the value `true`, every move must be either one cell horizontally or vertically in either direction and you are not allowed to make two consecutive moves in the same direction.

Comment: Is it allowed to visit a cell several times?

Comment: Yes, it is allowed. Can you please try to put it in some sort of pseudocode?

Comment: You can actually jump from one cell to another, they don't have to be neighbours, they just have to be on the same row or column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I missed that a move is not required to be between two adjacent cells - this enlarges the number of possible moves at each step but does not really change the general idea.

The easiest implementation is probably [depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) - you start at the starting cell and look at all possible moves - except for the first move there are at most three possible moves. For each possible move you do the same recursively until you reach the starting cell again or there is no possible move remaining. In the later case you track back one move and try the next possibility if there is one remaining.

You have to pass the direction of the last move along with the recursive call because this direction is not valid for the next move. If it is not allowed to visit cells several times you have to track the visited cells, too, and unmark them when tracking back. If it is allowed to visit cells several times you have to track the direction you left a cell when you visited it before in order to avoid cycles.

Using [breath-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breath-first_search) instead of depth-first search will avoid trying long paths that are no solutions at the cost of keeping book of a large number of partial solutions. [A* search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) might be another option to speed this up.

Side note: It may be the case that there is no value in visiting a cell several times because you could have take the other move directly when visiting the cell for the first time. The exception is doing the move not allowed when entering the cell for the first time
but I am not sure if such a path is possible.

Comment: You only have to keep track of one bit per node - whether the node was reached by a column move or a row move. So you could also do this by doubling the number of nodes, and linking only moves e.g. from a cell marked as "came here by column move" to one marked as "came here by row move" on the same row which might allow you to use some standard graph algorithm for your cycle detection.

Comment: Daniel and mcdowella thank you. I got it, I just need to figure out how to implement the recursion so I can know when to stop :-?

Comment: Is a single bit really sufficient? No need to distinguish between entering from left and right, top and bottom respectively? My other idea was to build a directed graph of possible moves and then just test reachability of the start node from the start node. But you need four nodes per cell because of the dependency of possible moves from the incoming direction and I decided that this is probably way to expensive. But when thinking about it again it seems much cheaper than performing a search.

Comment: @Cosmin normally with DFS you mark or number the nodes as you recurse. Finding a path to a node you have already marked is how you detect a cycle, and in any case you do not recurse down through a node that is already marked. You stop recursing when you get a cycle you want, or when you have marked everything.